# Android Studio: disable "web browsers" popup in the layout editor

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

With the latest update (1.2 preview) of Android Studio, it brings an annoying "web browsers" popup, which appears in the xml editor (top-right). It happens when opening XML, HTML or SVG files.

[image]

How to disable it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To disable it go to
`Settings...->Tools->Web Browsers`
and uncheck `Show browser popup in the editor`
[image]